# FreeType linking problems

Tags: c++, windows-phone, freetype

I'm writing a DirectX WindowsPhone app and I need to use FreeType with it. So ok, I've downloaded FreeType sources and used CMake to generate Visual Studio solution for WP ARM, but when I link freetype to my program it says `unresolved external __imp_FT_Init_FreeType` and stuff like that. I investigated a bit and found out that symbols in actual .lib looks like that: `_FT_Init_FreeType`, so no `__imp` prefix for them. It's kinda weird, because I use /MDd for both projects (VS just won't allow me to use /MTd for WP DX app) and I have no clue about what's going on. Is there any way to like add a prefix to all exporting symbols or any workaround for that, because I have no idea what to do with that.

I've tried compiling sources for x86 architecture with same output - actual program is looking for `__imp_FT_Whatever` but in lib they have no `__imp` prefix.

Prebuilt packages works fine for no particular reason (x86  only).

So, any ideas? Even small article could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. I added `FT2_BUILD_LIBRARY` as a preprocessor definition and everything compiles just fine! Hope that can be helpful.